# How to test Cloudinary rails and Attachinary with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cloudinary

I'm using the Cloudinary gem in my rails app, and am trying to build an Attachinary factory using Factory Girl.

All is fine except that the factory makes a request to the Cloudinary API, which I do not want to happen for each test.

Is there a way to mock the request? How can I get around this?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to mock it - show us the code you've tried so far (eg all the other bits of the spec) and we can help you with the specifics of the mock itself.

Comment: Check this comment https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/issues/113#issuecomment-282990631

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but someone my pump into the same sometime i think the best way when it to mocking [vcr gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) is one of the best

Comment: Try to summarize solutions here please. Links break overtime and your answer will be rendered useless.